# designing a website database search using FULLTEXT

Tags: mysql

I'm in the process of writing a search function for a website. The there are multiple tables I have to search through with my query, each with a different level of importance.

here is my current idea on the query

```
SELECT id FROM table1
WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('keyword')
UNION
SELECT id FROM table2
WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('keyword')
...
...
```

One of the issues I ran into was prioritizing results that fully match the keyword over others. So for example, if I have:

```
id - name
1 - Central Park
2 - Park
```

If I do a `FULLTEXT` search on that with keyword `Park`, it would evaluate both of them to have the same relevance. But I always want `2 - Park` to be on top of the results. I guess I can solve this problem by ordering with `LENGTH(name),` but is there another way around it?

Answer (score 0):

This page has some great info on scoring natural language search results.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html